# Bypass swagger in filters

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, servlet-filters, swagger-ui

I am working on spring boot. I have many filters that I have used. So each request flows through the filters. When I am using swagger, then even the swagger request is going through filters and throwing error. How do I bypass swagger in filters?

Comment: Is this security filters? maybe you could provide an example and a stacktrace?

Comment: This is filter is used to modify the request by adding a new header,i.e, the token. This token is getting generated from the values taken from request. Then this header is being used in all microservices. But swagger is unable to pass through the filter because it can't provide those information which is need to generte the token. Those information we will only get from our api related request. How do I bypass any url apart from my apis?

Comment: There are swagger configurations to either input token manually or via auto integration with auth server. If you don't want to do that, either you need to code your filter logic to be flag driven or your filter chain has to be flag driven & I am not sure of a way other than that.